# What is the android drag event priority for overlapping views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a parent view containing a number of child views. All views (parent and its children) implement a drag listener.

Can I guarantee that in the event of a drop event, the child view will receive the event before the parent view? It seems that way in my testing, but I can't find any documentation which confirms this as a deterministic behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the Z-ordering of your views. By default in android, if you define your views in xml, the Z-order is determined by the order of declaration of the views. Which means that the parent view is by default deeper in the hierarchy the its children views. You can use the Android Hierarchy Viewer to investigate this further. So, the default behaviour is the one you are describing. You can override it by using bringToFront() on views that are deeper in the Z-order. Hope this helps.

This is documented here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing